# Paperclip not resizing my images with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am finding it difficult to understand why paperclip is not resizing my images. I have followed the documentation and configured by development and production files by placing   `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"` in it.

I have double checked over my syntax in my post model and it seems fine to me. I have rendered the image_tag in my index view and my pictures are displaying, but not at the same size. My intention is to get paperclip to resize every image uploaded so I can have beautiful pictures to show everyone.

Here is my model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :image, presence: true
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

And my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <% @post.each do |post| %>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
        <%= post.caption %>
        </div>
       <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive"%>
       </a>
      </div>
        <% end %>
  </div>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I will provide other files upon request, if I can trust you.

Comment: Are your images uploaded with Paperclip correctly (I mean at least saved, whether the good size or not)  ? and what sie are you trying to get for your images ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what your other files look like but I'm actually using Paperclip on a project now and this is what I have in my Items Index Page.

```
<div class="card border-white" style="width: 15rem;">
<%= image_tag item.image.url, size: "250" %>
```

it could be you need to set the size and not

```
class: img-responsive
```

also, my Item poro looks like this

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord

has_attached_file :image,
:default_url => '/images/missing.jpg', styles: {thumb: "68x68#", 
medium: "300x300#"},
:path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:style/:filename",
:url => "/images/:id/:style/:filename"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: ['image/jpeg', 
'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/png']
```